# Regex to copy text to another before a specific character

Tags: regex

```
"test" = "data";

"text" = "data";

"this" = "data";
```

I got a long text like that one. I need to copy the first "" part to second "" part before the ; for each line.

**Expected result**

```
"test" = "test";

"text" = "text";

"this" = "this";
```

What regex can do this any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    "(.*?)" = ".*?"
Replace: "$1" = "$1"
```

### Demo